# How to delay showing of ToolTip ?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# tooltip doesn’t display long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225807/c-sharp-tooltip-doesnt-display-long-enough)

I need tool tip to be shown in 3 seconds after user move mouse cursor on the control, now it's shown immediately.

I tried this way:

```
this.toolTip.AutoPopDelay = 3000;
this.toolTip.InitialDelay = 3000;
this.toolTip.ReshowDelay = 3000;
this.toolTip.AutomaticDelay = 3000;

private void control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    toolTip.SetToolTip(control, "My info");  
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't work, it still is shown immediately, what I did wrong ?

Comment: This happens because you call SetToolTip() too often.  On the 2nd call, happens within milliseconds of the first one since the mouse is moving, the InitialDelay is canceled and the tip shows immediately.  The expected usage is that you call SetToolTip only once, normally in the form constructor.

Comment: There is a simple solution: [MSDN Instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984298(v=vs.71).aspx) that is valid for all VS versions. I used it in a VS2015 project.

Answer (score -1):

Change the `this.toolTip.InitialDelay = 3000;` to `this.toolTip.InitialShowDelay = 3000;` this will set the delay on show

Comment: I don't see that property on the help page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx

Comment: `.InitialShowDelay` property doesn't exist