# Is there a way to make a tooltip that stays visible as long as user is clicked in a TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I thought it would be easy but I just can't figure it out.

I would want something similar to the balloon caps lock warning that appears when typing password with caps on.

It would serve as a help with filling up the specific `textbox` in the form.

I managed to do something of that sort but it would always disappear when the mouse stopped hovering over an element. I need to to be shown when you click into the textbox and disapper when you change focus on different element so it isnt related to your mouse position and not shown for fixed amouunt of time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# tooltip doesn't display long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225807/c-sharp-tooltip-doesnt-display-long-enough)

Comment: It doesn't. I need it not to be dependant on mouse position and not be shown for fixed amount of time. I edited the post ot make it clearer.

Comment: I think that answer makes it clear that you cannot do that with a standard tooltip.

Comment: I think that the Enter and Exit events are what you want. Just make a `Label` visible on `Enter` and invisible on `Exit`.

Comment: [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider)